# i am unable to add dependency on my flutter project

Tags: visual-studio-code

[ad] flutter packages get
Running "flutter packages get" in ad...
Error on line 21, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source.

╷

21 │ ┌     sdk: flutter

22 │ │     flutter_native_admob: ^0.1.1+2

23 │ │

24 │ │

25 │ │

26 │ │

27 │ │   # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.

28 │ │   # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

29 │ │   cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

│ └──^

╵
pub get failed (65)
exit code 65

Answer (score 0):

**Add the dependencies like this**

```
//Correct way to add dependencies in flutter
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # Carousel Dependecy for sliders
  carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
```

instead of adding like this

```
//Wrong way of adding dependencies in flutter
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    # Carousel Dependecy for sliders
    carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
```

Here above code is take the dependency as flutter's child dependency.